# remove background effect input time

Tags: jquery, html, css

[input time focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggtrK.jpg)

I would like to remove the blue backgroundcolor from input time.
It is possible?

Picture in the link at the top.
Thx

```
 <input type="time" readonly/>

 <script>
 $('input[type=time]').dblclick(function(){
  $(this).prop('readonly', false) // and add color NOW
 })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the glow border, you can achieve that by addid this selector to your css styles:

```
input[type=time]:focus {
   outline: none;
}
```

Comment: no, is not the outline but the background color. I'm trying with input disabled iso inpur readonly and using jquery to enable on dblick maybe this will solve my problem